# GCP's Extend Memory in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

In GCP there is a "Custom Machine Type" choice to select, which allows selecting custom numbers of CPU and RAM. There is also a checkbox to select the "Extend Memory" option and then google allows to increase RAM more than 300 GB  per core.[image]

In AWS there are memory-optimized instances types that allow starting instances with 8 GB per core.

Is there any solution to this in AWS? I mean I need more than 8 GB per core, it is not mandatory to have so much RAM as google gives, but I need more than 8 GB, e.g. 14 GB per core.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the AWS hardware does not use NUMA, so there is no limit of "per core" memory. If you have a reference that shows differently, you should post it.

Comment: Or are you simply asking about the ratio between amount of memory and number of cores? In that case, no, you can't adjust that ratio for virtual machines. You can for Fargate task runners, but iirc you have a limited number of choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS supports the instance types that are listed on the [EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page, and *only in those configurations*.

The closest thing in AWS is Fargate, the container runtime, where you pick a CPU/RAM combination that fits your container – but it's nothing like what you can do in GCP (and the max RAM per core is even lower than what you can get in EC2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer )